# Convolution of two $l^{2}$ sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, convolution

Let $c, d \in \ell^{2}(\mathbb{Z}),$ then what can we say about their convolution i.e., Is it possible that $c*d$ also belongs to $\ell^{2}(\mathbb{Z}) ?$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Show your effort, for example by considering simple examples. There are  $99\%$  chances you  answer you question yourself.